# Solving an underdetermined system of linear equations among the rationals, in the neighbourhood of an approximate solution

Tags: linear-algebra, symbolic-computation

I have a system of linear equations $Ax=b$. Extremely underdetermined, for concreteness $x \in \mathbb{R}^{17,000}, b \in \mathbb{Z}^{156}$. $A$ is sparse, integer, full rank. I have a very precise approximate rational solution $\hat{x} \in \mathbb{Q}^{17,000}$ such that $|A \hat{x} - b| < 10^{-12}$. Unfortunately the theoretical conjecture that I'm trying to solve is only solved if I get an exact solution $x$, and it needs to be very close to $\hat{x}$, because it also needs to satisfy another $180,000$ inequalities that $\hat{x}$ satisfies.

I tried to solve least squares $||x-\hat{x}||^2_2$ via QR decomposition, and it almost works, but by design it gives irrational numbers, and the symbolic computations blow up. (I need to symbolically invert $R \in \mathbb{R}^{156\times 156}$ which consists of square roots of rational numbers with 900 digit numerators and denominators.)

I'd like to find any $x \in \mathbb{Q}^{17,000}$ such that $Ax=b$ is exactly true and $||x-\hat{x}||_2$ is smallish.

Comment: How about writing $x=\hat x+y$ and solving $Ay=b-A\hat x$ by LU decomposition?

Comment: How to guarantee that $y$ has small norm? More concretely, I believe LU decomposition leads to the task of solving some underdetermined $Uy=b'$ such that $U \in \mathbb{R}^{156 \times 17,000}$ is upper triangular. I don't know how to do that so that $||y||_{\infty}$ or $||y||_2$ is small.

Comment: Have you tried an exact rational LP solver such as QSopt_ex? Include upper and lower bounds for the rational solution to constrain it to be as close to $\hat x$ as you want.

Comment: Since your initial guess is pretty accurate, the new right hand side is very small already. I thought that standard LU decomposition with some generic choice for the degrees of freedom could work. Maybe worth a shot (but yes, no guarantee afaik).

Comment: Dániel, how did it work out? Curious minds want to know!

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Sorry for disappearing! I gave QSopt_ex a try but bumped into some issues. In the end we did something different, but if you write up your suggestion, I'll accept it, it's a perfectly good answer.